# Graphics And/Or Processor Issues Prevent Proper Portable Boot: Inspiron 7559 Skylake GTX 960M

Tags: boot, drivers, 16.04, hybrid-graphics, inspiron

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 16.04.1 from a terabyte HDD to my Dell Inspiron 15 i7559.  The hardware setup is as follows:

- i7 6700HQ
- GTX 960M 4GB discrete graphics
- Intel HD 530 integrated graphics

Probably none of this matters:

- 1 TB HDD
- 500 GB SSD
- 16 GB RAM

In any case, the boot disk, which works fine on other computers, has all sorts of problems here.

I start by disabling secure boot in the BIOS and enabling legacy boot, which has a USB boot option.

If I boot it without changing anything right now, it boots to a blank purple screen.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> yields a tiny flashing cursor in the top left of the screen, but then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>'s purple screen is removed, showing a journal error, and trying to boot.  There are all sorts of messages about processor #4 hanging for 25 seconds, hex codes from who knows where, and something about a fatal kernel error.  In any case, the boot never completes.

There are tons and tons of AskUbuntu questions about reconciling ubuntu and the 7559, be it in booting, seting up dual booting, sleep issues, or switching the graphics processor to the nvidia one, but none that I found directly address my issues and my attempts at applying suggested solutions from them have been met with varying degrees of failure.

By using `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` and `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line in grub, I can boot to the <kbd>F1</kbd> terminal, but the <kbd>F7</kbd> graphics part of ubuntu is frozen - switching to that freezes the screen until I switch back to the terminal.

I also tried booting from recovery mode, from which I just continued normal boot.  There was a message about some graphics cards requiring a full graphical boot, so if the graphics didn't work, just reboot, and then it did actually boot to the login screen...  But it was stuck on the login screen:  I entered my password a few times, and if correct, it just refreshed the login screen ("login loop"), and if incorrect it mentioned as much.  Very useful...

Also, I wasn't connected to internet, so it's hard to poke any nvidia driver versions or settings if that's something I should try.  Can you join a wifi from the command line?  Also, the only WiFi I have access to has no password, but requires authentication at a web location after you connect, which makes it slightly more complicated...

When you add the nvidia ppa, you get the following message:

> ### Current Status
>
> We currently recommend: `nvidia-367`, Nvidia's current long lived branch.
>   For GeForce 8 and 9 series GPUs use `nvidia-340`
>   For GeForce 6 and 7 series GPUs use `nvidia-304`

Many of the recommendations involve various versions (I saw 354, 361, 362).  Perhaps I should be trying 340 or 367?

What should I be doing to fix this problem and get Ubuntu to boot properly?  Are there any places to look for logs that would help others with more experience to properly deal with this problem?  And is it just me, or is either Dell, Intel, or Nvidia doing a really bad job with something?!